# Make http request before displaying page in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux

ComponentWillUnmount is no longer recommended in React. I want to send a request to the server to see if the user is logged and then update the state before actually displaying the page. I don't know how to do this with React hooks or a way that is recommended in React.

Answer (score 0):

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think
> of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and
> componentWillUnmount combined.

The following demonstrates componentDidMount , componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount

```
useEffect(() => {

  // function to run to check if user is log in
 

},[]) //<-- similar to componentDidMount , empty array, run once.


useEffect(() => {

}, [state]) //<-- similar to componentDidUpdate. Run when state changes.


useEffect(() => {

  return () => cleanUp //<-- similar to componentWillUnMount, clean up functions.
}, [])
```

Recommended reading for [useEffect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Recommended reading for [setting state with hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Example of checking user login

```
const Component = () => {
   const [ loggedIn, setLoggedIn ] = useState(false) //set login initial state to false

   useEffect(() => {
       const checkLogin = async() => {
             const checking = await fetch(api);
             if (checking) {
                  setLoggedIn(true)  //set login state to true
             }
       }
       checkLogin()


   },[]) //<-- run once when component mounted


   return (<div>{ loggedIn ? 'Logged In' : 'Not Logged In' }</div>)
}
```